# Programmatically cut and paste shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using the source code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.paste to cut and paste a shape from one slide to another. It has worked well in the past.

Recently I have had an issue where I get an error on the paste function which says that the clipboard is empty. When I use the VB editor to step back and then step forward it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed fairly often on StackOverflow. The search feature should turn up a few suggestions.

There are two usual reasons for this kind of problem:

- Asking PPT to paste a format that's not on the clipboard
- It can take time for the Copy part of the operation to complete, and if your paste command immediately follows the copy, there may not (yet) be anything on the clipboard.

Try something along these lines (aircode):

```
Dim oShp as Shape
' Copy the [whatever]
On Error Resume Next
While oShp is Nothing
  Set oShp = ' paste here
Wend

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Steve, thanks for your observations. However, I cannot see that either reason is valid. The first reason for saying this is that it works most of the time, and then suddenly it throws a hissy fit and says the clipboard is empty. There is no predictability to which shape it fails to copy onto the clipboard. They are broadly all the same type of shape, and indeed some are identical. All the shapes where they are being copied from have unique names. so I am at a loss to see what the issue is. Perhaps you could explain your code a little better

Comment: Steve, thanks for your help. I have found a much better way that suits my longer term strategy better. That is to export all the shapes into a folder and then I can insert them where I like and when I like without worrying about any differences due to this copy and paste issue

Comment: As to your first comment, the code I posted keeps pasting/testing to see if anything pasted until it gets a positive, then proceeds.  As to the second, glad you have a better way for your needs.